How can I create a SwiftData Query Predicate with multiple optional conditionals?
I am using SwiftData and searchable and would like to create a dynamic predicate that matches the search string to 3 properties of the SwiftData object.  All three properties are optional so that I can use CloudKit with my SwiftData model.  But because they are optional I cannot unwrap in Predicate body.  Instead this is what I am trying:
let predicate = #Predicate<Person> {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        return true
    } else {
        
        return (
            ($0.firstName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false) ||
            ($0.middleName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false) ||
            ($0.lastName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false)
        )
    }
}

This will work with one or two properties.  But when I add the third property I get the compiler cannot type-check in time error.
How can I simplify this so that I can use all three optional properties for comparison in my predicate body?  Or is there another approach I should be taking?

Why does properties need to be optional because of CloudKit?

I should say needs to be optional or default value but in my case I want optional.  Currently I have default values and it works but I want to see if it's possible with optional which fits my requirement.

Yes I also came to the conclusion that it works if they are not optional.

I think this answer also satisfies this question.

The more conditions you add to the Predicate, the more expressions the macro produces. To get the type-checking time down under the compiler's limit, either

simplify the predicate, for example in this case replacing the build_Conditional created with the if { … } else { … } with a top level build_Disjunction by flattening to a chain of || operators.
let predicate = #Predicate<Person> {
   searchText.isEmpty ||
     $0.firstName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false ||
     $0.middleName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false ||
     $0.lastName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false
}

or

split the predicate into smaller ones and combine the results from calling evaluate(_:) on each.
let firstNamePredicate = #Predicate<Person> { $0.firstName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false }
let middleNamePredicate = #Predicate<Person> { $0.middleName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false }
let lastNamePredicate = #Predicate<Person> { $0 lastName.flatMap { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) } ?? false }
let predicate = #Predicate<Person> { searchText.isEmpty || firstNamePredicate.evaluate($0) || middleNamePredicate.evaluate($0) || lastNamePredicate.evaluate($0) }



